# Google Fit: What is DataType Floor of Google Fit.

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I want to get value floor from the Google Fit. But I not found about data type of floor.

This is my code.

```
private void setDailyFloors() {
PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> dailyFloors = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mClient, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE);
dailyFloors.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DailyTotalResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(@NonNull DailyTotalResult dailyTotalResult) {
    if (dailyTotalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
      DataSet totalSet = dailyTotalResult.getTotal();
      if (totalSet != null) {
        floor = totalSet.isEmpty() ? 0 : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY).asInt();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any related to a Data Type Floor in the [Google Fit documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types), maybe this one is a custom data type.

Just check this [link](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#custom_data_types) to know more about Custom data types.

To create a custom data type for the first time, use the [ConfigApi.createCustomDataType](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/ConfigApi.html) method:

```
// 1. Build a request to create a new data type
DataTypeCreateRequest request = new DataTypeCreateRequest.Builder()
// The prefix of your data type name must match your app's package name
.setName("com.app.custom_data_type")
// Add some custom fields, both int and float
.addField("field1", Field.FORMAT_INT32)
.addField("field2", Field.FORMAT_FLOAT)
// Add some common fields
.addField(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY)
.build();


// 2. Invoke the Config API with:
// - The Google API client object
// - The create data type request
PendingResult<DataTypeResult> pendingResult =
ConfigApi.createCustomDataType(mClient, request);


// 3. Check the result asynchronously
// (The result may not be immediately available)
pendingResult.setResultCallback(
new ResultCallback<DataTypeResult>() {
@Override
public void onResult(DataTypeResult dataTypeResult) {
// Retrieve the created data type
DataType customType = dataTypeResult.getDataType();
// Use this custom data type to insert data in your app
// (see other examples)
...
}
}
);
```

Just read the above links to know more about it. Including the, How to 
Retrieve your custom data types and How to Create data points of custom data types.